# Yum failing conditions

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, meego

I would like to now what happens if yum starts updating and during update user (force)shuts down computer ? What are the dangerous parts of update process if user shut down pc ?

Comment: Should be posted on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2):

Anytime after yum says "starting transaction" is a bad idea to stop.

You can try and recover with "yum-complete-transaction" and/or "yum history redo last", but it's better to just not do that.